# How to install visual studio code in debian 8.7?

Tags: debian, software-installation, debian-installer

From the official web: I downloaded the code..amd64.deb file, and install with the terminal command as superuser:

```
dpkg -i code-.deb
```

with and without later:

```
apt-get install -f
```

and all looks fine, but graphical start menu I click the visual studio code icon and show "processing", but never start the app

I tried the terminal commands:

```
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor > microsoft.gpg
sudo mv microsoft.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.gpg
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repo/vscode stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list'
apt-get update
apt-get install code
```

that recommend the web: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux#_rhel-fedora-and-centos-based-distributions

and don't work.

Instead .deb should download .tar.bz or what?

[image: terminal_install_VScode]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded 3 days ago, the 1.12 version of Visual Studio Code 64-bit DEB.
I run Debian 8 64-bit.
I do not use GNOME, but use RazorQT (I uninstalled GNOME since I am on a vm).
Dependency is libxss1 (as root : apt-get install libxss1).
Now install VS Code. And you can now launch it.

Now I need to beautify it by following [this guide](https://www.sitepoint.com/visual-studio-code-linux/) .